# Wordpress custom title not showing in header or browser tab

Tags: wordpress, title, custom-fields

I have added a Custom Field to one of my pages, with the name 'title' and added the code below to functions.php, but the title still renders as the default. Does anyone know what could be causing this? I am using a custom theme based on Underscore. The fields are in the postmeta table in the database and the ID's match.

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

add_filter( 'wp_title', 'change_page_title_callabck', 10 , 2 );
function change_page_title_callabck( $title , $separator) {
    if( is_single() ){ 
        $custom_post_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'title', true);
        if( $custom_post_title ){
            $title = $custom_post_title ." ".$seprator." ";
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```